# Why this functional test are failing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, minitest

I am using `minitest` framework and all test cases are working fine except the test case for `create` method in `controller` class

## Test cases

```
def setup
 @user  = users(:pal)
 @post = posts(:one)
end

test 'should create a new one' do
sign_in @user
assert_difference 'Post.count'  do
  post :create, post: { name: @post.name, data: @post.data, user_id: @user.id}
  end
  assert_redirected_to post_path(assigns(:post))
end
```

Where as `.yml` file are for user and post

## users.yml

```
Amit:
  email: test1p@gmail.com
  encrypted_password: <%= BCrypt::Password.create('render') %>

pal:
 email: test2@gmail.com
 encrypted_password: <%= BCrypt::Password.create('render') %>
```

## post.yml

```
one:
 id: 1
 name: 'test'
 data: 3

two:
  id: 2
  name: 'value'
  data: 3
```

While running this test cases I am getting

```
 "Post.count" didn't change by 1.
    Expected: 2
      Actual: 1
```

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: There's not enough information here to say for sure.  The error message indicates that your test is failing to create the new Post which probably means that you're not passing valid or complete parameters to the `post` request, but without seeing your controller and model, it's impossible to say.

Comment: Also, you probably want to be getting the `user_id` for your new post from the logged in user and not passing it in as a parameter to the controller.  Doing it your way would allow anyone to create a new Post as any other user which you probably don't want to do.